# Cant create animation in android studio: resource identifier not found

Tags: android

I created a simple xml animation under `res/anim/rotate180.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromdegrees="0"
        android:pivotx="50%"
        android:pivoty="50%"
        android:todegrees="180"
        android:toyscale="0.0" />
</set>
```

But i cant run my project:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027fromdegrees\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sourcePath":"\\src\\main\\res\\anim\\rotate180.xml","position":{"startLine":3},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027pivotx\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sourcePath":"\\src\\main\\res\\anim\\rotate180.xml","position":{"startLine":3},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027pivoty\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sourcePath":"\\src\\main\\res\\anim\\rotate180.xml","position":{"startLine":3},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027todegrees\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sourcePath":"\\src\\main\\res\\anim\\rotate180.xml","position":{"startLine":3},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027toyscale\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sourcePath":"\\src\\main\\res\\anim\\rotate180.xml","position":{"startLine":3},"original":""}
```

Isnt that the correct way to create an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the attributes in your animtion.xml properly defined.  The names are case sensitive, so you need to change them.

For example, you need to change: *fromdegrees* to *fromDegrees*  (notice the CamelCase?)

Here is an example I have (that works) with the proper attribute definiton:

```
<rotate
    android:duration="1200"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```